# How to find out oramts for oracle 12c is installed using registry entry in windows 2008r2 server?

Tags: installation, oracle12c, mts

We are using a custom setup program to do our installation. For our application to run we need oramts installed, before we install the application we do a prerequisites test to check if we have all the required components installed. With the earlier version we used the registry key "`[SOFTWARE]\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1\ORAMTS_CP_TRACE_DIR`" to find if oramts is installed. But with the current installation we are not able to find what registry key is to be used.

Comment: After manual installation of the service by running oramtsctl.exe, you will find it in registry in the Oracle home itself. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 12c client, **Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server** is not a part of installation. You must explicitly run the **OraMTSCtl utility** to create the OraMTS Service.

```
C:\ORACLE_HOME\bin> oramtsctl.exe -new
```

Once it is done, you can verify from **services.msc** that the **OraMTS** service is created.

Quote from docs,

> OraMTS Services Run as Oracle Home User
>
> OraMTS services now operate as a specified, lower privileged user (the
>   Oracle Home User). A utility is provided for cases where the service
>   must be created manually rather than by the installer. Each Oracle
>   Home now has its own OraMTS service.

Please see the documentation for [Manually Creating an Oracle MTS Recovery Service](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTMTS/install.htm#NTMTS303)

**UPDATE**

Adding a screenshot -

[image]

Above screenshot, "**ORACLE**" is the home for the 12c client, and has its own **OraMTS service**.